# How can I use Java to run OS commands

Tags: java, windows, command, cmd

I'm making a program and that must call *Clafer* with `clafer -m=xml Case5.cfr`.

So I use

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("clafer -m=xml " + "Case5.cfr");
pb.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\unituser\\workspace\\com.unitbilisim.clafer2Ecore\\src\\model\\"));
Process P = pb.start();
```

but always get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "clafer -m=xml Case5.cfr" (in directory "C:\Users\unituser\workspace\com.unitbilisim.clafer2Ecore\src\model"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at EmfCompare.emfCompareDeneme.main(emfCompareDeneme.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to separate the program name from its arguments, each needs to be in a different string element of a String array or String List.

Answer (score 2):

try as

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clafer -m=xml Case5.cfr", null, new File("C:\\Users\\unituser\\workspace\\com.unitbilisim.clafer2Ecore\\src\\model\\"));
```

or

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("clafer", "-m=xml", "Case5.cfr")
   .directory(new File("C:\\Users\\unituser\\workspace\\com.unitbilisim.clafer2Ecore\\src\\model\\"))
   .start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("OS command");
```

**EDIT**
you can also use `ProcessBuilder`

check [this link](http://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/) for examples of both